# Using MacOS Sierra (iMac) as Web Server

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, imac, macos-sierra

I've got a client who uses an older iMac running OS X 10.5 to serve as a LAN web server. It's been running fine for 7+ years. We recently purchased a new 21.5" iMac with MacOS 10.12 Sierra to replace the older iMac. The problem I am having is that the new iMac is losing network connectivity ~15 minutes after the screen goes to sleep. I have set System Prefs -> Energy Saver to..

- Turn display off after 5 minutes
- Checked: Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when display is off

It seems logical that this setting should keep the iMac awake and available for incoming network connections, as it did in 10.5, but it isn't. I have used

```
sudo systemsetup getcomputersleep
```

and confirmed that sleep is indeed set to "Never". I recently checked "Enable Power Nap" in the Energy Saver prefs pane hoping that this might have the undocumented effect of keeping network connections awake. So far this seems to be working but I am looking for a definitive answer about how to keep an iMac running MacOS Sierra awake and available for network connections as a web server.

**UPDATE 2015-02-07**

After turning on "Power Nap" in the Energy Saver prefs the machine stays awake as expected. I was out of town for a week and when I came back I was able to connect with no delays. I then turned off "Power Nap" expecting it to revert to the previous state of becoming unresponsive but it has now been a week later and it is still responding just fine. I don't know what to make of this and wish I could have a definitive answer as to why the machine was initially not staying awake.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all I did with mine was set the 'Computer sleep' slider to never & the Display sleep to 'something comfortable' as I use it as a desktop too. It hasn't slept since 2008, nor ever lost connectivity. I also set 'start automatically after power failure' just in case. I'm using ethernet - maybe WiFi could respond differently, I've never used it, so can't comment.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did on the older iMac. The problem is that newer iMacs do not have the slider for "Computer Sleep". Instead there is just the display sleep slider and a checkbox to prevent computer from sleeping when display sleeps. I have that checked but it has not been working. I'm using ethernet with wifi turned off. Yesterday I also checked "Power Nap" and that seems to be keeping network connections alive for the past 24 hours so hopefully that is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Install Caffeine.  I just did this today with a 2008 MacBook Pro running OSX 10.9; this should also work though for macos 10.12.

From the **`man`** page:

> **caffeinate** creates assertions to alter system sleep behavior.  If no assertion flags are specified, **caffeinate** creates an assertion to prevent idle sleep.
>        If a utility is specified, **caffeinate** creates the assertions on the utility's behalf, and those assertions will persist for the duration of the utility's
>        execution. Otherwise, **caffeinate** creates the assertions directly, and those assertions will persist until **caffeinate** exits.

You can also install it with **homebrew**: `brew cask install caffeine`

After installing you can then create a daemon or agent with `launchctl` to ensure that `caffeinate` is executed whenever the iMac restarts.